# Select value with maximum number of entries - Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, max, greatest-n-per-group

This is what I have:

A table `PATENT` with a column `ASSIGNEE`. I want to find the `ASSIGNEE` with maximum number of entries in the table.

And this is what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT ASSIGNEE
FROM (
    SELECT ASSIGNEE, count(*) num_assignee
    FROM PATENT
    GROUP BY ASSIGNEE
    ORDER BY num_assignee DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

This works great for only one maximum, however, in the case of a tie, the other `ASSIGNEE` is not shown. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
SELECT assignee
FROM (
    SELECT assignee, 
           count(*) num_assignee,
           MAX(count(*)) OVER () max_num_assignee
    FROM patent
    GROUP BY assignee
    )
WHERE num_assignee = max_num_assignee;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
SELECT assignee 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 assignee, count(*) num_assignee
    FROM patent
    GROUP BY assignee
    ORDER BY num_assignee DESC
) Source
```